# ReReplace the url of a CFChart

Tags: url, coldfusion, replace, coldfusion-8, cfchart

I am working on a chart the has the output of a series of surveys that were taken. The CFChartData Item is the name of a category, and the value is the average score that was given to the category. The chart works fine, but I need to have the chart url be something other then the item name, because the Friendly Url system we are using wont allow %20 to be used in a Get Url (and most of the Category names have spaces, that get replaced with %20 by the CFChart). I also can't change the name of the Categories on the chart (having - or _ instead of spaces on the chart, cause the chart item to not wrap, and then the chart image only shows every other category name).

Is there anyway to assign an alternate ID to be used (for instance a current row, or an assigned unique id) or possibly Replace the %20 that are being used in the URL with - or _ but not on the chart itself (I tried to do a ReReplace inside of the URL, but it runs before $ITEMLABEL$ gets assigned, causing an error.)?

Edit- Might as well add the code as well, even though it's fairly generic (and doesn't include the attempts I have made, its just the code I am using for now)

```
<cfchart format="png" scalefrom="1" scaleto="#max#" chartwidth="675" url="#request.site_url#Drivers/Name/$ITEMLABEL$.html">
<cfchartseries type="Bar" colorlist="##000000">
    <cfloop query="getGraph">
        <cfchartdata item="#Name#" value="#totalratings#">
    </cfloop>
</cfchartseries>
</cfchart>
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can do what you're looking for using cfsavecontent.

```
<cfsavecontent variable="theGraph">
<cfoutput>
<cfchart format="png" scalefrom="1" scaleto="#max#" chartwidth="675" url="#request.site_url#Drivers/Name/$ITEMLABEL$.html">
    <cfchartseries type="Bar" colorlist="##000000">
    <cfloop query="getGraph">
        <cfchartdata item="#Name#" value="#totalratings#">
    </cfloop>
    </cfchartseries>
</cfchart>
</cfoutput>
</cfsavecontent>

<cfset theGraph = replacenocase(theGraph,"%20","-","ALL")/>
<cfoutput>#theGraph#</cfoutput>
```

My replace logic is just an example, you can do anything you want with the string before rendering it.